# Do linear algebra and ring theory give any worthwhile results for spaces of continuous/differentiable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ring-theory, function-spaces

Typically, at the beginning of linear algebra texts (and often ring-theoretic ones as well), by way of example of structures being discussed, one is told that the set of all continuous (or differentiable) functions forms a vector space/ring , after which all mention of it promptly ceases. My question is the following: does the apparatus of linear algebra/ring theory lead to any serious structural results for sets like these?

Comment: Functional analysis is essentially this with a metric or topological structure included. There are several dozen books and thousands of papers on the topic [rings of continuous functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=rings+of+continuous+functions). Also, a recent area of investigation is [lineability and algebrability](https://www.google.com/search?q=lineability) (see [this survey paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2014-51-01/S0273-0979-2013-01421-6/) and [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1482299097)), which roughly involves large vector subspaces of pathological functions.

Comment: I had the suspicion that this is what functional analysis studies, guess this was a dumb question... Could you in a few words state what major results there are akin to stuff like the Jordan form for finite-dimensional vector spaces (asking out of curiosity)? Is it possible to give complete classifications as with fin-dim vector spaces or does the infinity of dimension inhibit that somehow?

Comment: Classifications *of what*?  Rings of continuous functions have various properties of course, often depending on their underlying topological space's topology.

Comment: @rschwieb perhaps "classification" is the wrong word, but for fin-dim vector spaces there are many results that significantly simplify one's understanding of the spaces, such as the simple fact that every space $V$ is isomorphic to $K^{\text{dim}V}$, or the more advanced fact of the Jordan form that completely describes the conjugacy classes of operators on the space. What I meant is, are there any "broad" and useful results like this for rings/spaces of continuous functions?

Comment: If your question was _pedagogical_, something like: why function spaces are not used to illustrate results in linear algebra? then one possible answer is precisely that most simple results do not hold for infinite dimensional spaces. Of course this is opinion-based...

Comment: The question is not pedagogical, as I am entirely unfamiliar with the realm of functional analysis. I was simply curious to get an overview of how it works for inf-dim cases.